# AutoCompleteTextView : Load list first then query on client or update it through Async Calls?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit2, autocompletetextview

I have an activity that contains an AutoCompleteTextView.

This AutoCompleteTextView is a list of thousands and thousands of entries.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1- Load the huge list first and populate the AutoCompleteTextView.

2- Async Calls when the user is writing and updating the AutoCompleteTextView adapter dynamically.

Other than the obvious cons of 1 and 2 (Huge load on the client in 1 and huge load on the server in 2). Which is the most optimal solution and the one most considered when handling such a case?

Comment: how many entries do you have? 10s, 100s, 10000s? more?

Comment: @pskink Hello, thanks for your reply, as I said, thousands and thousands but to be exact less than 10 thousand but they are ever growing. So it could hit more than that. I don't have an exact exact number. But Of course I would like a scalable solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- Load the huge list first and populate the AutoCompleteTextView.

Best if you load the data "outside" the app with a `SyncAdapter` and update your local SQLite database, so that the `AutoCompleteTextView` can use a `CursorAdapter` to get the data.  This is a good option if your list doesn't change all that much.  However, it mandates all the complexity of maintaining a local database and using `SyncAdapter` including unattended authentication, possibly with a custom authenticator.

> 2- Async Calls when the user is writing and updating the AutoCompleteTextView adapter dynamically.

This is what we do in our app; I would recommend this approach.  Here are some pointers:

- Limit the number of results you send back on any single request, say around twenty.  In our app, some common items are requested more often than others, so we prioritize the results to include those items.  Your user isn't going to scroll very far through the list anyway; if their desired item isn't included, they can type another character or two to get it.
- Put a timer on the `AutoCompleteTextView` so that the user has to stop typing for 200-250 milliseconds before the request is sent to the server.  This will help to ensure that the request is sent only when it's necessary and cut down on server bandwidth.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer !

The list I want to load is only a 1-time thing when the user is signing up, so I prefer to not go into the hassle of loading them into a database. 

I like your solution of giving a 250 ms delay between calls. Is there a way of waiting for the user to stop tying in AutoCompleteTextView ? After text change will update on every single character he writes.

Comment: @PampaZiya That's right, so when the user types you have to start some sort of timer, then fire the remote request when the timer expires and cancel the timer if the user types another character.  Frustratingly, this logic is actually built-in to the abstract `Filter` class, but Google has marked everything hidden.  There are probably about five different ways to do this depending on the specifics of your adapter class and remote service implementation, so I recommend that you just start coding.  When you get stuck, post another SO question and the community can help you from there.